# JavaScript: destructuring with a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to get `firstName` and `lastName` properties from a whole `user` object. I need to use a conditional statement too.
How to do something like that?

`getUserById(id)`and `getUserByAddress(id)` use the JavaScript `find()` method that returns an element or `undefined`.

```
let { firstName, lastName } = getUserById(id);
if ({ firstName, lastName } === undefined) {
  { firstName, lastName } = getUserByAddress(id);
}
return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
const { firstName, lastName } = getUserById(id) || getUserByAddress(id) || {};
if (firstName && lastName) {
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}
return "Unknown user";
```

If `getUserById(id)` is falsy, `getUserByAddress(id)` will be executed. If this is falsy, too, `{}` will at least prevent throwing an error.

Comment: Simple and elegant. You can add a few words to explain it just in case.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! It looks great! :)

Comment: "will at least prevent throwing an error" I am not a front end developer but in back end that is a horrible way to think. It leads to SO many vague hard to diagnose issues.

Comment: @Marie it's actually just the null object pattern. I am pretty sure you use it all the time in the back end - one prominent example is returning an empty collection instead of `null`. So, nothing new under the sun.

Comment: Thanks @Marie You are right. But error handling would be part of another question I guess.

Comment: You could add comments....I think this pattern is or should be well-known @epascarello

Comment: This only works if the value returned by `getUserById` is a falsy value. If `getUserById` really returns an object that doesn't have those properties this will not work.

Comment: @MinusFour *the premise of the question* suggests it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @vlaz A collection is a thing  that can be empty. In this case you have to check if the object exists first and then you have to check whether it is the type of object you expected. If the consuming code doesnt realize this was done this way they will end up with "Name: undefined". IMO if you are going to use the null object pattern you should just use it normally and return null.

Comment: @Marie but with null objects the whole point is that you DON'T return `null` to avoid problems like `obj.name` throwing an exception. And indeed, in JS that construct wouldn't thrown an exception for an empty object. Hence why `obj || {}` is a common pattern to save the consuming code from null guards. In a strictly typed language with the null object pattern you'd return something like `new Person()` which will have both ID and name set to nothing. You'd do that because you have no choice - you have to return a Person and it has to have those fields. In JS `{}` is valid enough.

Comment: @vlaz The point I am making is that returning `{}` will return `undefined` when somebody tries to get `result.firstName` and it will render undefined to the client. To prevent rendering the string "undefined" to the client you have to check whether the name is defined. If you have to check whether it exits regardless why not let it fail-fast?

Comment: @Marie I changed the answer a little bit. But I still see checking for firstName and lastName as a better solution. Could also be that an empty object is returned. We don’t know what is happening in the functions. Interesting point though. When do conventions count before error handling?